# Apache Ignite ARM Unsafe GetFloat Segmentation Fault

Tags: crash, segmentation-fault, ignite

I am currently wondering if Apache Ignite could be used on an ARM device with Java 8u60 for ARM installed.
I tried so on my "odroid u3". I installed ignite 1.3.0 incubator on the odroid together with the current oracle 8u60 JDK, took the example-config.xml, adapted my IPs and started ignite.sh. After a while I got the info about the Cluster info and ignite was waiting.
Then I started the little demo "count the characters" on another computer. It took a while them I see my odroid had crashed with:

```
[20:02:01] Ignite node started OK (id=0510043f)
[20:02:01] Topology snapshot [ver=1, server nodes=1, client nodes=0, CPUs=4, heap=1.0GB]
[20:03:12] Topology snapshot [ver=2, server nodes=2, client nodes=0, CPUs=12, heap=4.5GB]
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGBUS (0x7) at pc=0xb68a176c, pid=4000, tid=1859777632
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_33-b05) (build     1.8.0_33-b05)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (25.33-b05 mixed mode linux-arm )
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x72c76c]  Unsafe_GetFloat+0x5c
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/volker/development/apache-ignite-fabric-1.3.0-incubating-bin/bin/hs_err_pid4000.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

Anyone can help here? Is it in general possible to work with Ignite on an ARM based device?

Comment: I have posted this question on the Apache Ignite dev list: http://s.apache.org/ignite-arm-unsafe . I will monitor the discussion there and will provide an update here.

Comment: In case you would need a core dump or the java log... just tell me

Comment: I think that core dump and java log would definitely help. Can you please provide it?

Comment: I got it here now... ca. 2GB uncompressed, 26MB compressed with 7z. How does the file get to you ?

Comment: I am not sure if it helps for the effort to fix the problem with "Unsafe": I read that the "Unsafe" class will not be accessible anymore in Java 9.

Comment: @magicroomy Mentioned problem should be fixed in Ignite 1.6. See ticket https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-2080 You can build latest Ignite version from sources and try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guys from Apache said they solved the issue in 1.6.0, so I tried a nightly with a simple example and it really seems to work. Good work guys !